Why does this Rust test case succeed?
I wrote a test case to test references and copies, expecting to get the result of references due to copies, but it was the opposite.
#[test]
fn test_expression_ref() {

    fn factorial(n: usize) -> usize {
        (1..n + 1).product()
    }

    let iterations = 10_000_000;

    // Measure time for using reference
    let start = Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..iterations {
        let r = &factorial(6); // avoid data copying
        let _ = r + &1000;
    }
    let duration_ref = start.elapsed();

    // Measure time for not using reference
    let start = Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..iterations {
        let result = factorial(6); // data copying
        let _ = result + 1000;
    }
    let duration_no_ref = start.elapsed();

    println!("Time with reference: {:?}", duration_ref);
    println!("Time without reference: {:?}", duration_no_ref);
    assert!(duration_ref > duration_no_ref); // It should fail here.
}

duration_ref should be less than duration_no_ref.

In this precise scenario, it is reasonable to think that the compiler just optimized away both loops, and that you are just comparing how much time it takes to measure the elapsed time.

^ And even if for some reason it doesn't eliminate the loops, it's surely optimizing away the reference.

^ And even if it doesn't, then it should be the opposite: duration_no_ref would be less than duration_ref.

In debug mode, duration_ref is longer than duration_no_ref (as expected). But it's useless to measure times in debug mode anyway. In release mode, the compiler optimizes away everything and both have the same duration (40 ns on the playground).

This is heavily dependent on "what" and "which" and other questions. I believe I have read somewhere that reference is in general the fastest method of passing larger pieces of data around in Rust. You will get different results based on the size, the access, possible the type and to mix it all up, even your environment and other running processes can affect the results. The same benchmark test could differ in end results depending on your system.
I made some very un-scientific tests, and on my system, the fewer iterations i made the relatively slower the reference method became, while it would catch up as i increased the # of iterations.
In the lower end of iterations the reference was taking twice the time as the no_reference, and as i increased the time difference would decrease. By the 10_000_000 mark the difference was less than 1%.
Currently it is iterating through 1_000_000_000_000_000, and by the time of writing this, it wasn't finished. yeah.. didn't really think that one through when I clicked run!
